# Master included as device on I2C bus?

Tags: i2c, pullup

Hi When calculating the pull up resistor value using the formula R = 50 / d, where d is the number of devices on the bus, is the master considered a bus device?

for e.g. If I have a micro controller master and two slave devices on the bus should this count as a total of 3?

For extra credit: Am I using the right formula? if I use 3 as number of devices this tells me I should use 16k6 pull-ups, which seems high...
Ta

Comment: At what (bit) frequency do you want to run that I2C bus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three. Electrically the master controls the bus in exactly the same way as the slaves.

I'm not sure where your formula comes from. The [spec](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf) states that pull-up resistors are to be chosen in function of bus capacitance and speed(page 55):

[image]

Comment: "function of bus capacitance"  -  Which would be a related to the number of devices surely? Ta

Comment: "in function of bus capacitance" and speed.

Comment: @Telaclavo - Yes, shown in the graphs, but not in the answer. I'll edit it.